# Change the button color with 'If'

Tags: python-2.7, button, tkinter

So basically, this is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import math # import module matematika
import tkFont
import time

class PersamaanKuadrat:
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        self.parent = parent

        #self.parent.geometry("1280x560")
        self.parent.title(title)
        self.parent.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW")

        self.aturKomponen()

        self.entP2.focus_set()

    def aturKomponen(self):

        self.customFont = tkFont.Font(family="Helvetica", size=18)

        mainframe = Frame(self.parent, bg="grey", bd=1)
        mainframe.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

        # Label Rumus
        Label(mainframe, text="PT PARKIR SEJAHTERA", bg="grey", font=self.customFont).place(relx=.055, rely=.1)
        Label(mainframe, text="HARAP SIMPAN BAIK-BAIK TIKET ANDA", fg="red", bg="grey", font=self.customFont).place(relx=.055, rely=.25)
        Label(mainframe, text="LANTAI 1", fg="red", bg="grey", font=self.customFont).place(relx=.55, rely=.35)
        Label(mainframe, text="LANTAI 2", fg="red", bg="grey", font=self.customFont).place(relx=.55, rely=.65)     
        # input data:
        Label(mainframe, text="1st input", bg="grey").place(relx=.05, rely=.35)
        self.entP5 = Entry(mainframe)
        self.entP5.place(relx=.15, rely=.35)

        Label(mainframe, text="2nd input", bg="grey").place(relx=.05, rely=.40)
        self.entP4 = Entry(mainframe)
        self.entP4.place(relx=.15, rely=.40)

        Label(mainframe, text="3rd input", bg="grey").place(relx=.05, rely=.45)
        self.entP3 = Entry(mainframe)
        self.entP3.place(relx=.15, rely=.45)

        Label(mainframe, text="4th input", bg="grey").place(relx=.05, rely=.50)
        self.entP2 = Entry(mainframe)
        self.entP2.place(relx=.15, rely=.50)


        Label(mainframe, text="5th input", bg="grey").place(relx=.05, rely=.55)
        self.entP1 = Entry(mainframe)
        self.entP1.place(relx=.15, rely=.55)

        Label(mainframe, text="6th input", bg="grey").place(relx=.05, rely=.60)
        self.entP0 = Entry(mainframe)
        self.entP0.place(relx=.15, rely=.60)


        self.btnCariAkar = Button(mainframe, text="ENTER!",
            command=self.onCariAkar)
        self.btnCariAkar.place(relx=.25, rely=.35)

        btn1= Button(mainframe, padx=30, pady=30, text="A1", bg="white")
        btn1.place(relx=.65, rely=.25)

        btn2 = Button(mainframe, padx=30, pady=30, text="A2", bg="white")
        btn2.place(relx=.80, rely=.25)

        btn3 = Button(mainframe, padx=30, pady=30, text="B1", bg="white")
        btn3.place(relx=.65, rely=.55)


        btn4 = Button(mainframe, padx=30, pady=30, text="B2", bg="white")
        btn4.place(relx=.80, rely=.55)

    def onCariAkar(self, event=None):


        A = float(self.entP5.get())
        B = float(self.entP4.get())
        C = float(self.entP3.get())
        D = float(self.entP2.get())
        E = float(self.entP1.get())
        F = float(self.entP0.get())
        disk = A+B+C+D+E+F






class JamDigital:
    """ Kelas Jam Digital"""

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        self.parent = parent

        self.parent.title(title)


        #buat variabel String untuk teks jam
        self.teksJam = StringVar()

        self.aturKomponen()
        #melakukan looping untuk tampilan jam
        self.update()

    def aturKomponen(self):

        mainframe = Frame(self.parent, bg="grey", bd=1)
        mainframe.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

        #teks jam dibuat dengan komponen Label, yang bisa berubah
        #setiap waktu
        self.lblJam = Label(mainframe, textvariable=self.teksJam,
                            font=('Helvetica', 40))
        self.lblJam.place(relx=.05, rely=.45)



    def update(self):
        #strftime() berfungsi untuk merubah waktu secara lokal
        #menjadi bentuk string yang kita inginkan.
        datJam = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime())

        #mengubah teks jam sesuai dengan waktu saat ini
        self.teksJam.set(datJam)

        #perubahan teks jam dalam selang waktu 1 detik (1000 ms)
        self.timer = self.parent.after(1000, self.update)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()

    aplikasi = PersamaanKuadrat(root, "Tugas Akhir")
    aplikasi = JamDigital(root, "Tugas Akhir")
    root.mainloop()
```

If I want to change the color of 4 buttons in the right side
by changing the value of 1st input until 6th input, what should I do.

For example:

if I fill all input (first input until 6th input) with 1, and press the <kbd>enter</kbd>, the background color of 'A1' will change to yellow
if I fill all input with 2, and press the <kbd>enter</kbd> the back ground color of 'A1' will change to red
and if I fill all input with other number, the background color of 'A1 will change to green

I can't figure it out, so I need the help, thanks

Comment: So,you need help in changing color or with the 'if' statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `self` for buttons as well. Change the color using:

```
if disk==6.0:
    self.btn1.configure(bg ="red")
```

Use the above in the method `onCariAkar()`

Comment: Hi @user3611502 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: thanks shaktimaan, it works :) actually this is my first time learning python and tkinter, can I ask you another question? if I just want to use 1st input to change the A1, 2nd input to change A2, I think I must change the 'float' from A right? but I don't know what I should change it with, thanks again :)

Comment: If you are thinking of pressing "Enter" just after the 1st input,then just change the `if` condition to 1.0,2.0...& so on

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the button an instance variable (`self.btn1`, for example), if you want to access them from another method of the class, as was suggested in @shaktimaan's answer.

A simpler way to change the color conditionally (not writing a ton of `if variable == number` statements) would be to access colors through a dictionary that holds the number (6.0, 12.0, etc) as keys, and colors as values:

```
self.color_map = {6.0: 'red', 12.0: 'yellow'} # change or add keys and values as needed
```

Then, in the `onCariAkar()` method, you could use a `try...except` block to change the color if the corresponding number is one of the keys in the dict:

```
try:
    color = self.color_map[disk] # set color to the value of key in dict
    self.btn1.config(bg = color) # change btn1 color
except KeyError:                 # disk is not a key in self.color_map
    pass                         # do nothing on key error
```

Comment: Yes, i think this would be a better(performance wise & otherwise) approach